# What is the Probability of a Very Large Digit Constant Number to be Exactly Divided by 19?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let's just put the 40s and 8s side by side randomly to create a 4002 digit number. We have a chance to do this once. Is it possible to talk about the probability of dividing the created constant by 19 exactly? A number is either a multiple of 19 or it isn't. So I thought the answer to this question was 1/2. But such a large number probably won't be divisible by 19. Would it be more accurate to say that the probability of such a situation cannot be defined?

Comment: What does it mean "Let's just put the $40$s and $8$s side by side randomly"? Are you talking about creating a number made only by $40$ and $8$? Like $40408$ or $884084040$ but of $4002$ digits?

Comment: We create a 4002 digit number in the form of 4084084040404040408884040... This is a random operation and we only have one chance to generate a number.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a sample space of all the $4002$ digit numbers that can be made by putting substrings of $40$ and $8$ together.  It is a finite collection.  You can then compute how many of them are divisible by $19$.  If you sample your space randomly the chance that the number you get is divisible by $19$ is just the second divided by the first.  I would guess it is not far from $1/19$